# How to style Pagination Item from Pagination in Material-UI, ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

**Summary**
Hi, everyone!  In this question, I would like to ask you how to style child component when you import parent component only from material-ui.

**Problem**
I would like to override Pagination Item's class imported from Material-UI. I just import Pagination component from Material-UI. How can I access child component (Pagination Item component) style from Pagination component?

For example. I want to apply this style to Pagination Item component.

```css
.Mui-selected {
  "background-color": "transparent";
  "color": "#19D5C6";
}
```

I have below TSX code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';

// This style doesn't reach to Pagination Item
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      'selected': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      },
    },
  }),
);

export default function BasicPagination() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Pagination count={10} className={classes.root} />
  );
}
```

**What I have now**

[image: Design I have now]

**What I want to have**

[image: Design I want to make]

**References**:

- Pagination Demo: https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/
- Pagination API: https://material-ui.com/api/pagination/
- Pagination Item API: https://material-ui.com/api/pagination-item/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Mui-selected` can help you with that like that:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>({
  root: {
      '& .Mui-selected': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        color:'#19D5C6',
       },
  }),
);
```

or (without the code up there) :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>({
  selected: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        color:'#19D5C6',
    },
  }),
);
// .... rest of code
const classes = useStyles();
return <Pagination
            count={10} 
            className={classes.root} 
            renderItem={(item)=> <PaginationItem {...item} 
                           classes={{selected:classes.selected}} />}
            />
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. You made my day. Is ```root``` in useStyles is related to ```.MuiPagination-root```?

Comment: not exactly.. the className prop in pagination component is related though... u can call it whatever u want. if u would pass it through classes prop then u should pass it like this : classes={{root:classes.<the name u choose>}}

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand much better. Have a good day!

Comment: How do I add CSS for unselected buttons?

Comment: @ SiddharthPrajosh  What approach of the two did you choose?

Answer (score 4):

Style CSS for unselected buttons

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>({
      root: {
          '& ul > li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) > button:not(.Mui-selected)': {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            color:'#19D5C6',
           },
      }),
);
```

Comment: how to call it in the Pagination component, is it `classes={{ ul: useStyles().root }}`?